# nodejs body-parser not able to get data

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

```
var express = require('express'); // Express instance to access its 
var path = require('path');
var mongoose = require("mongoose"); // mongodb ODM

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000); //
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')));

mongoose.connect(config.MONGO_DB_URI, function(error){
  if (error) {
      console.log("Oops! Connection Failed! " + error);
  } else {
    console.log("Ahoy! Connection Successful with Mongo!");
  }
});


app.use('/api', function(req, res){
  console.log("dasasasa");
  console.log(req.body);
});

module.exports = app;
```

when I log `req.body` it is an empty object {}.
Also the version of body parser is:

```
npm body-parser -v
2.15.9
```

What can i be missing here?
Also I am trying it with postman.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure, you set up your request data in postman correctly?

Comment: hey it worked when I made it x-ww.form-urlencoded, didn't get it though

Answer (score 0):

The bodyParser object exposes various factories to create middlewares. All middlewares will populate the req.body property with the parsed body when the Content-Type request header matches the type option, or an empty object ({}) if there was no body to parse, the Content-Type was not matched, or an error occurred.

Make sure you're using some thing like:

Client.js:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/yourRoute',
    data: data,
    dataType: dataType,
    success: function(data) {
         //do something
    }

});
```

and server.js

```
app.use('/yourRoute', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body) // should be data from client
})
```